# How to monitor SQL Server backups with Nagios?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008, nagios

How can I set up Nagios to monitor the health of SQL Server (SQL Agent) backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [nagios exchange.](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer)

The plug-in [check_mssql_health](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer/check_mssql_health/details) will probably do what you want.  i.e. database-backup-age

Otherwise it's up to you to write your own probe, which shouldn't be too hard.